# Change Javascript variable image source based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

Apologies in advance if this question has already been answered. I've searched through StackOverflow (as well as other sites) and any similar questions didn't seem to help me. Anyway, here is my dilemma:

**I have a radio button that should control the image source of a javascript variable.**
**Essentially, I want the image to change on click** and have this occur in a way that requires the least amount of changes on the page.  I realize this is likely a simple request but I am not that experienced in JavaScript and this has been driving me up a wall.

For some background info on how exactly my page is built:

Everything is contained in a Drupal module. The Drupal modules connect to our main server which hosts many webpages and applets. The individual applet is built with Javascript, jQuery, CSS+HTML.

I cannot share the code as it is work under an employer, but if you want me to elaborate further or give some pseduocode I can do that.

Thanks!

(P.S. - This is my first time posting to StackOverflow and I think I followed community guidelines but if there is any advice on how I could better pose my question (and any future ones) please drop me a line!)

Comment: Assignment or not you are able to narrow the code to where the problem lies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way

**HTML**

```
 <img id="my_image" src="http://i.imgur.com/tL6nW.gif" alt="">

     <br>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="http://i.imgur.com/tL6nW.gif" checked>Image1<br>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="http://i.imgur.com/BfZ5f.gif">image2
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('.radio').on({
    'click': function(){

        var image_url=$(this).val();
        $('#my_image').attr('src',image_url);
    }
});
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKxCz/1/)

If you want to make it completely dynamic you can initialize the image element's default image at the page loading time too.
The additional code will be something like this.

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){
 $('#my_image').attr('src','default.gif');
});
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your response!  Apologies on my late response, but I tested what you recommended and it seemed to help.  Thanks for taking the time to aide me.

Comment: @vxela: thanks for he comment, and I am glad it helped. :)

You can accept the answer and close the question if your query was adequately answered else you can ask if you need any further clarification.
 Cheers :)